# Install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express using C#

Tags: c#, installation, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am in a situation where I need to Install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express silently. I want to use C# for this but couldn't get a working solution.

Can someone post a working C# code for above scenario?

Comment: I don't think usage of C# is good idea for silent install of SQL Server, since its own installer already has silent mode switch`/Q`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Following code worked for mee..

```
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\temp\SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe",
    @"/q /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=SQLSILENT /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SQLSVCACCOUNT=""NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=""BUILTIN\Administrators"" /AGTSVCACCOUNT=""NT AUTHORITY\Network Service"" /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=true /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=""Password@123""");
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    p.Close();
}
```

For only windows authentication remove /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="Password@123"

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as assembling a command line by following the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(v=sql.105).aspx

Then just call `Process.Start("Setup.exe /q /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSVCACCOUNT="<DomainName\UserName>" /SQLSVCPASSWORD="<StrongPassword>" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="<DomainName\UserName>" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS");`